# AWS ALB Authorization bearer token from X-AMZN-OIDC-*

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I am using https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/

The AWS ALB redirects to a custom url for authentication and after user login, ALB adds the header X-AMZN-OIDC-* to the request to downstream service. However, the downstream service expects the "Authorization: Bearer token" in the header.

Is there any mechanism to use the X-AMZN-OIDC-* header value and create a new header named Authorization with the value Bearer token where token value is same as the X-AMZN-OIDC-* header value?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I‘m interested

Comment: No I didn't find a clean solution yet. But you can hack it by putting a nginx in between and copy the amazon header value into a new header for bearer token